# Is it valid to use %lu in a format string for printf where PRIu32 would be expected?

Tags: c, int, format-specifiers

Assuming I have, for example, a variable `i` of type `uint32_t`. The expected way to print it would be like that:

```
printf("%"PRIu32"\n", i);
```

However, it should be noted that it is required for `long unsigned int` to be at least 32bits wide. The correct specifier for `long unsigned int` is `%lu`. Thus, can the above statement be replaced with:

```
printf("%lu\n", i);
```

I’d suppose yes, since I can see no reason why not. However, if yes, then this would remove the need for existence of these macroified specifiers like PRIu32, so I figure I’d better ask.

The reason I’m asking it is that I’d like to create a format string for `printf` dynamically, and it’d be hard to allocate space for this format string if I don't know the size of the string `PRIu32` expands to (and whether `sizeof(PRIu32)` is valid or not may be worthy of a separate question).

In any case, I suppose it should be valid to write:

```
printf("%lu\n", (long unsigned)i);
```

Comment: what standard your following C99 or C89?

Comment: @LethalProgrammer C11.

Comment: Alright, you got the answer already.

Comment: "**at least** 32bits wide" - noticed something? And why do you expect it to be `unsigned long`, not `unsigned int`?

Comment: I don't see where the problem is using the correct version. `PRIuN` expands to a string literal, as much as `"ul"` is. What keeps you from using the macro? TGhe only difference is a bit more typing, which is never an argument against writing correct code.

Comment: @Olaf again, I don't know if `sizeof(PRIuN)` is valid, and I’ve already learned that when it comes to C I shouldn't rely on something I think should be valid but I don't know for certain.

Comment: @gaazkam: What is unclear about "PRIuN expands to a string literal, **as much as "ul" is**."? If you don't believer me, read the standard! Maybe you want to recap from a good C book what preprocessor macros are?

Comment: @Olaf I believe you, but I obviously hadn't read your comment when I was posting my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Thus, can the above statement be replaced with:
>
> ```
> printf("%lu\n", i);
> ```
>
> I’d suppose yes, since I can see no reason why not.

No, because `long unsigned int` can be *larger* than 32 bits, or if exactly 32-bits can nevertheless have a different representation than does `uint32_t`.

> In any case, I suppose it should be valid to write:
>
> ```
> printf("%lu\n", (long unsigned)i);
> ```

Yes, and as you observed, it is also *safe*, because `long unsigned int` is required to be able to represent all the values that a `uint32_t` can take.

Comment: Under what circumstances can an implementation define `uint32_t` and have a 32-bit `unsigned long` (`long unsigned int` is an alternative name for `unsigned long`), and yet have different representations?  §7.20.1.1 _Exact integer types_ says that you shall only define `int32_t` if the implementation supports it as a two's complement representation with 32 bits and no padding bits, and `uint32_t` is the corresponding unsigned type. If the machine uses one's complement or sign-magnitude, the exact-width integer types should not be defined. But that rules them out for 'different representation'.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the standard does not require that there be only one integer type with any given combination of size and signedness, or that two such types share a common representation.  For example, there could be two such types with different byte orders, or with different numbers of padding bits.  These could both be standard integer types (e.g. `unsigned int` and `unsigned long`) or one could be among the implementation's extended integer types.

Comment: OK — I'm not going to chase down the standard on such possibilities.  They are so outlandish that I'd be more than astonished if you have ever come across one, and fairly astonished if you ever do.